# Old lapack .dylib is being linked instead of the current version

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, lapack

I use lapack in an exact diagonalization program.

Using `otool -L V3.e` I am told that I have linked to the library "/opt/local/lob/lapack/liblapack.3.dylib". In the very same directory is the library "liblapack.3.8.0.dylib". The implication here is that the latter is a new version of lapack and is therefore desirable.

I can't figure out how to link to one over the other. My current compiler flags for linking to this library is:

```
-0fast -I$(DIR) -L$(DIR) -llapack
```

Where `$(DIR)` is the directory shown above.

I don't have admin permission but can easily ask the person in charge of the MacPorts. So if the its possible to remove one of those libraries I can make that happen.

**EDIT**: In response to Gavin Portwood.

```
... -L$(DIR) -llapack3.8
```

For this one all module files compiled well but the linker failed with the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -llapack3.8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [V3] Error 1
```

I tried a variant with 3.8.0 at the end instead of 3.8 and got the same result.

```
... -L$(DIR) -l:liblapack.3.dylib
```

Slightly confused about this one since I don't want to use the this library.  But with this one I was given the same error as above. If I change it to `l:liblapack.3.8.0.dylib' I get the same error.

```
... -L$(DIR) /opt/local/lob/lapack/liblapack.3.dylib
```

This last one didn't give me an error but a warning. The warning is as follows:

```
warning: /opt/local/lib/lapack/liblapack.3.8.0.dylib: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Note that I did correct your typo. The program seems to have run correctly but when I ran `otool -L <exe>` I was linking to liblapack.3.dylib. Also, my compiler is gfortran.

**EDIT2**: Directory contents /opt/local/lib/lapack/

```
cmake                   libcblas.3.dylib        liblapacke.3.8.0.dylib
libblas.3.8.0.dylib     libcblas.dylib          liblapacke.3.dylib
libblas.3.dylib         liblapack.3.8.0.dylib   liblapacke.dylib
libblas.dylib           liblapack.3.dylib       pkgconfig
libcblas.3.8.0.dylib    liblapack.dylib
```

**EDITFINAL** Turns out the directories were soft linked. See Comments on Gavin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler and version, link with one of the following:

```
... -L$(DIR) -llapack3.8.0

... -L$(DIR) -l:liblapack.3.8.0.dylib

... -L$(DIR) /opt/local/lob/lapack/liblapack.3.8.0.dylib
```

Comment: I tried these to no success. I'll edit my post with what I did.

Comment: Had a typo with the version number, try them again

Comment: I updated my post. I figured you had a typo so I went with 3.8.0 as at the end of all three options. As I said in my edit, the last one compiled with a warning but linked to 3.0 anyways. **EDIT** I updated my post again with the contents of the library directory.

Comment: Do `ls -l /opt/local/lob/lapack/liblapack.3.dylib`. Is /opt/local/lob/lapack/liblapack.3.dylib soft linked to /opt/local/lob/lapack/liblapack.3.8.0.dylib?

Comment: When I do this I get: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  21 Oct 12 11:37 /opt/local/lib/lapack/liblapack.3.dylib -> liblapack.3.8.0.dylib` Is this soft linked?

Comment: Yes, the two libraries are identical